# .Net Custom Service could not start

Tags: asp.net, windows, service

I created a custom Windows Service and I am trying to start it through command prompt:

```
C:\Windows\system32>net START "CustomService"
The CustomService service is starting.
The CustomService service could not be started.

The service did not report an error.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.
```

I tried looking at HELPMSG 3534. It states: The service did not report an error. I do not know where to go from here. I tried googling this, but nothing really helpful. I am really do not know how to troubleshoot this.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    SetConfigVariables()
    _logger.WriteMessageToLog(SimpleLog.LogType.InfoType, "Start Service")
End Sub
```

The SetConfigVariables() calls sql server and pulls some data and set appropriate global variables.

Comment: without the code most anything we say is pointless.  I do know that I received similar errors when I first started writing services because I was never actually leaving the "OnStart" method in the service.

Comment: i added my onstart method

Comment: Q: Did you resolve this?  If so, exactly what was wrong, and *how* did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Q: Did you get this working?

SUGGESTION:

If not, make sure you've done everything in this article, particularly:

> [MSDN Walkthrough: Create a Windows service
>   app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)
>
> Before you can run a Windows service, you need to install it, which
>   registers it with the Service Control Manager

ALSO:

Q: How are things going with this question: [Accessing Config File From Web - No AppSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091913/accessig-config-file-from-web-no-appsettings/55095520#55095520)