# Accessing Config File From Web - No AppSettings

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, configuration

I am working on a project that requires me to modify the .config file for a Windows service (written in ASP.NET) I wrote. The changes need to be made from an administrative website I am developing. When the user selects the 'UPDATE' button on the web app, the code below is executed:

```
Protected Sub ModifyAppConfig()
        Try
            Dim configFile = "C:\App\App.exe.config"
            Dim configFileMap As New ExeConfigurationFileMap
            configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFile
            Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration
            config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
            config.AppSettings.Settings("LogDirectory").Value = txtLogDirectory.Text '* EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE *
            config.Save()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

When the application is trying to access "LogDirectory" AppSettings index, an exception is thrown. `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
During debugging, the `AppSettings.Count = 0`. How come none of the AppSettings are imported?

I know that it is correctly opening the file because there are ConnectionString data. Below is the config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="conn" connectionString="Data Source=DBASE;Initial Catalog=NGDevl;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="LogDirectory" value="C:\CTemp\"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

How can I access and modify the AppSettings("LogDirectory") value?

Comment: It sounds like maybe your app.config wasn't updated?  1) Is this an "app.config" ... or "something else"?  2) Is the executable a .Net .dll or .exe, and exactly how/where is it deployed on your filesystem?  3) Is the app.config *IN THAT PATH* correct?  4) Let's say your dll is "MyService.dll".  Is there a corresponding "MyService.dll.config" in that directory?  Does it have the correct "add key" in "appSettings"?

Comment: This is .net windows service. The file is app.exe.config. The path is correct.

Comment: Q:  Does it have the correct "add key" in "appSettings"?  Q: What happens if you add the line `Dim currentLogDir = config.AppSettings.Settings("LogDirectory")`?  Is it "Nothing"?  If not, does it have a "Value" property?

Comment: returns nothing (null)

Comment: OK: Your app.config syntax is correct, your filepath is correct, and your "open" appears to be succeeding.  1) Consider if [ConfigurationUserLevel.None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationuserlevel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) might be causing grief.  2) Verify you can read *anything* from the [Configuration](https://nicolaspeters.wordpress.com/tag/openmappedexeconfiguration/) config object you've opened.

Comment: See also [Get the App.Config of another Exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53553/421195)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I don't see anything wrong with your program.

I've created a VB.Net/Console mode MCVE that might help your troubleshooting

**Module1.vb**

```
Imports System.Configuration

'
' EXAMPLE OUTPUT:
'   Reading config file(test.exe.config)...
'   config.AppSettings.Settings("LogDirectory") : C : \CTemp\
'   connectionStrings: <connectionStrings>
'   <add name = "conn" connectionString="Data Source=DBASE;Initial Catalog=NGDevl;
'   Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
'     </connectionStrings>
'   appSettings: <appSettings>
'   <add key = "LogDirectory" value="C:\CTemp\"/>
'     </appSettings>
'   startup: <startup>
'   <supportedRuntime version = "v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
'     </startup>
'   3 sections were found.
'
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ' Get filename
        Dim args() As String = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
        If args.Length <> 2 Then
            Console.WriteLine("USAGE: ReadAppConfig <\path\to\app.config>")
            Return
        End If
        Dim configFilePath As String = args(1)

        ' Open config file
        Try
            Console.WriteLine("Reading config file(" & configFilePath & ")...")
            Dim configFileMap As New ExeConfigurationFileMap
            configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFilePath
            Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration
            config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None)

            ' Try to read AppSettings["LogDirectory"]
            Dim obj = config.AppSettings.Settings("LogDirectory")
            If IsNothing(obj) Then
                Console.WriteLine("config.AppSettings.Settings(""LogDirectory""): NULL")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("config.AppSettings.Settings(""LogDirectory""): " & obj.Value)
            End If

            ' Dump all Sections
            Dim ct As Integer = 0
            For Each section As ConfigurationSection In config.Sections
                Dim xml = section.SectionInformation.GetRawXml
                If Not xml = Nothing Then
                    Console.WriteLine(section.SectionInformation.Name & ": " & xml)
                    ct = ct + 1
                End If
            Next
            Console.WriteLine(ct & " sections were found.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Console.WriteLine("ERROR:   " & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

**test.exe.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn" connectionString="Data Source=DBASE;Initial Catalog=NGDevl;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="LogDirectory" value="C:\CTemp\"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

- **Project > test.exe.config:** I set the "Copy to Output" property to "Copy if Newer"
- **Project > Properties > Debug:** I set "Command line arguments" to "test.exe.config"

'Hope that helps...